# ConstrainLayout editor adding unnecessary constraints or margin making it impossible to use

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I really like the constraintLayout but I'm forced to use it in Text mode since the Design mode is completely buggy.
When I try to add constraints directly onscreen it justs messes up the layout entirely, creating fixed margins and unnecessary constraints. The worst part is that sometimes it looks like the constraints are well applied in Design mode (the layout seems correct), but when I switch back to Text mode, it adds completely random constraints and it's really frustrating.

I'm using Android Studio 2.3.3 which is the latest Release version

Is there a way to fix this ?

Comment: Android Studio 3.0 beta 7 has bug fixes for the ConstraintLayout Editor.

Comment: Thank you it's actually way better

Comment: The editor will never be as good as if you're building your layout in the text, so sooner or later in your layout building process, you have to edit the text. If you're experienced, it's even faster to do it in the text and just check the editor if it works.

Comment: I think it depends on the complexity of the layout, but yes at some point it becomes impossible to use the editor. Still I like to use the editor to quickly position the first views

Comment: At this time, I prefer using text editor only. It's way better.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do all the dragging inside blueprint mode, then edit/add/remove any extra constraints inside the 'Properties' drawer on the right side of Android Studio. You can click on the blue dots to delete, edit the margins manually, and set vertical/horizontal bias.